# decode UTF-16 text

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

I have a Java servlet that receives data from an upstream system via a HTTP GET request. This request includes a parameter named "text" and another named "charset" that indicates how the text parameter was encoded:

If I instruct the upstream system to send me the text `TĀ` and debug the servlet request params, I see the following:

```
request.getParameter("charset") == "UTF-16LE"
request.getParameter("text").getBytes() == [0, 84, 1, 0]
```

The [code points](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ucs2.html) (in hex) for the two characters in this string are:

```
[T]  0054
[Ā]  0100
```

I cannot figure out how to convert this `byte[]` back to the String `"TĀ"`. I should mention that I don't entirely trust the `charset` and suspect it may be using `UTF-16BE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`String(byteArray, charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor:

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 84, 1, 0 };
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-16BE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling getBytes() at all? You already have the parameter as a String. Calling getBytes(), without specifying a charset, is just an opportunity to mangle the data.